# Sticky bar ignoring z-index in Google Chrome

Tags: jquery, html, css, google-chrome, z-index

I added a navigation bar (ribbon style) to a website that I'm currently working on and used the jQuery Sticky Plugin to make it make it fixed to the top of the viewport when the user scrolls.

It works perfectly in Firefox, but Chrome disregards the z-index of the sides of the ribbon as soon as the bar sticks. I have spent the last 7 hours googling for a solution to this. I've tried a range of different recommendations including un-nesting the bar and setting positions and z-index values manually for all elements, but to no avail. In fact, I ended up starting from scratch because I had only made it worse trying to fix it.

Could anyone please tell me what I should change to fix the sides of the ribbon when scrolling in Chrome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not ajust border-width and bottom position of `.DropMenu:before` and `.DropMenu:after` to bypass the inconsistent behavior of `z-index`?

```css
.DropMenu:before {
    border-color: transparent;
    border-color: rgba(40,54,44,.99) rgba(40,54,44,.99) transparent transparent;
    left: -1px;
    bottom: -12px;
}

.DropMenu:before, .DropMenu:after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 6px;
}

.DropMenu:after {
    border-color: transparent;
    border-color: rgba(40,54,44,.99) transparent transparent rgba(40,54,44,.99);
    right: 0;
    bottom: -12px;
}
```

PS. The pseudo class `:before`, `:after` are not likely supported by lower version of IE.

Comment: This worked perfectly. Thank you so much! What do you recommend I do to mitigate the IE incompatibilities? Is there a preferable way to acheive this?

Comment: @DanielM. Replace `:before`, `:after` with some empty nodes, eg. two `span`s, and add styles to the two `span`s.

Answer (score 0):

There is an error on that page which is like this

```
      TypeError: Cannot read property 'msie' of undefined
```

And because you are using Jquery 1.9.1 this error is obvious. `$.browser` have been [removed from 1.9](http://jquery.com/upgrade-guide/1.9/#jquery-browser-removed). You can use [jQuery Migrate](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-migrate/) to have `$.browser support`.

The error is in this [js file](http://tradingvega.com/analyses/wp-content/themes/skeleton/javascripts/jquery.formalize.min.js?ver=1.2.3).

Answer (score 0):

I saw where you made mistake....please do following to make it work perfect in everybrowser:

1) Remove your ribbon img from body.

2) Make a new class:

.topbg{float:left; width:100%; height:25px; z-index:9999; background: url(../images/border_top.png) repeat-x top center; position:fixed;}

3) Put this new class in your HTML:
   
      
     and your content

Hope this helps.....

Comment: The ribbon is not an image, it's a gradient. The issue is with the edges of the ribbon.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {
            if ($(this).scrollTop() > 50) {
                $('.nav').css({"position":"fixed", "top":"0"});
            } else {
                $('.nav').css({"position":"absolute","top":"50px"});
            }
        });


    });

});
```